# Change selling price of products using Views Bulk Operations in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, view, ubercart

I am new with Views Bulk Operations Module. I want to be able to change selling price of the attributes by doing calculations on cost price.

1. In VBO choose nodes (ubercart products)
2. Select and Execute arbitary PHP script - to write!
3. By aplying the script the following changes are done:

   - in table 'uc_product_options' parameter 'price' is calculated as ('price' = 'cost' *1.2) for each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately someone's beaten you to it :)

[Ubercart Product Actions](http://drupal.org/project/uc_product_actions)

> If you have lots of products in your shop, and you ever wanted to do any of the following, this module will surely help:
>
> - Decrease the price of some/all products in your shop by 20%, or
> - Manually set the weight of some/all product to 0, or
> - Increase the price of some/all products in your shop by $3

If that module doesn't have the exact combination of actions you're looking for, just peek through the code and it should be easy to work out how to adjust it for your needs.